# How to test if bandit algorithm is converging?

Tags: multiarmed-bandit

I have coded up the a multi-armed bandit algorithm based on algorithm 1 in the original [LinUCB algorithm paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0146.pdf), but I am having trouble determining if it is working properly.

My test setup is the following:

- I created some random context data matrix, with `D=np.random.random(
  (10000,3))`, where each row is a training example (user) and each
  column is a feature for that user / training example. Each row is
  $x_t$ from the algorithm.
- I then created 100 arms where each arm is represented by a Bernoulli 
  distribution with varying $p$ (probability) values.

In fact the logic    of each arm's reward distribution is the following:

```
if random.random() > self.p:
    return 0.0
else:
    return 1.0
```

- The different p-values of the arms are defined by
  `np.random.random(100)`, which means I know what the best/worst arms
  are beforehand.

The test then follows these steps:

1. Step through each row of $D$ from $x_1$ to $x_{10000}$
2. At each $x_t$, go through every bandit arm, from $a_1$ to $a_{100}$ and estimate the payoff, $p_a$, using the formula from the paper.
3. Choose the arm with the highest estimated payoff, call this $a_t$.
4. With the recommended arm, $a_t$, sample its Bernoulli distribution using the logic above with its respective $p$-value. Call this $R_{t,a}$. At the same time, sample best arm's reward (arm with highest $p$ value), call this $R_t^*$
5. Calculate $Regret=R_t^*-R_{t,a}$ and record this at each step $t$.

Now, after running this, according to the paper, the cumulative regret over each time step should be logarithmic or $O(\sqrt{KdT} )$. But when I plot the cumulative sum of Regret over each timestep, it is simply linear. Where am I going wrong? What other methods could I use to tell if it is converging?

**Note**: I haven't posted all my code as I wanted to make sure the broader approach made sense and was correct before going into the nitty-gritty details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the way at the end of the right column on page 3, [the LinUCB paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0146.pdf) says:

> "we can adapt the analysis from [6] to show the following: if the arm set $\mathcal{A}_t$ is fixed and contains $K$ arms, then [...], and then prove the strong regret bound of $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{KdT})$, matching the state-of-the-art result [6] for bandits satisfying Eq. (2)."

Now, that last part ("for bandits satisfying Eq. (2)") is slightly ambiguous in my opinion, it can be interpreted in two different ways:

1. That bound was the state-of-the-art for bandits satisfying Equation (2), OR
2. This particular paper **also** relies on Equation (2)

I didn't go through the referenced paper (reference [6]) yet to see if the actual analysis also requires Equation (2) to hold, but I suspect it does. Right above Equation (2), the LinUCB paper does say:

> "[...] we assume the expected payoff of an arm $a$ is linear in its $d$-dimensional feature vector $\mathbf{x}_{t, a}$ with some unknown coefficient vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}_a^*$; namely, for all $t$,
>
> $$\mathbf{E} \left[ r_{t, a} \vert \mathbf{x}_{t, a} \right] = \mathbf{x}^{\top}_{t, a} \boldsymbol{\theta}_a^*$$"

Generally, when a paper says "we assume" like that, that indicates that their later theoretical results rely on that assumption unless they later on specifically indicate for one of their theoretical results that it does not rely on that assumption. So, now it's time to see if that assumption actually holds in your case.

Unless I'm misunderstanding a part of your description, it looks to me like the context vectors $\mathbf{x}_t$ are actually useless in some sense; they do not in reality have any relation whatsoever to the reward distribution. This kind of means that you have a standard Multi-Armed Bandit problem (not contextual), but it's "disguised" as a Contextual MAB problem.

In your case, the rewards are completely independent from the context vectors, which means Equation 2 from the paper cannot hold; the expectation of the reward given a context vector cannot be a linear function of that context vector. The assumptions of the theoretical analysis leading to that regret bound do not hold, so the results do not hold either (at least, not necessarily; they still might by coincidence).

---

Note that, in your case, **under the assumption that you're learning a separate parameter vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}_a$ per arm $a$**, there is a very easy way to make the assumption of Equation (2) hold; simply add a fourth feature to every feature vector $\mathbf{x}_t$ which always has a value of $1$ (very much like an "intercept" or "bias" term that's often used in things like Linear Regression, Logistic Regression, Neural Networks, etc.). Hopefully, the algorithm should then be able to learn that the three other features are completely useless for predictions, and learn to predict a consistent estimate of the expected rewards of all the arms independent of the remaining three features.

---

The following procedure was described in the question for evaluating regret:

> 4. With the recommended arm, $a_t$, sample its Bernoulli distribution using the logic above with its respective $p$-value. Call this $R_{t,a}$. At the same time, sample best arm's reward (arm with highest $p$ value), call this $R_t^*$
> 5. Calculate $Regret=R_t^*-R_{t,a}$ and record this at each step $t$.

I was inclined to say that this was not 100% correct, but it actually does appear to be correct according to the formal definitions of regret.

I didn't originally feel like it was 100% correct, because **the best arm with respect to expected reward ($p$) is not necessarily the best arm in any single given round**. This evaluation method can theoretically lead to negative regret (consider the case where a suboptimal arm was played, but that suboptimal arm randomly got "lucky" and produced a better reward in one particular timestep).

Before looking up the formal definitions, I was inclined to say that a better evaluation method would be to generate the actual reward outcomes in a time step for all arms, and subtract the reward of the chosen arm from the best possible reward in that timestep to compute that timestep's regret. In comparison to your evaluation method, this approach;

- can never result in a negative regret
- is more "strict" / punishing for suboptimal strategies
- results in a regret of precisely $0$ for a "cheating" or "oracle" strategy that always knows which arm is the best and picks the best

When comparing the performance of multiple different algorithms, both variants of computing regret would always lead to the same *ordering* of algorithms' performance levels.

Comment: Thanks so much. This makes sense and explains why even if though the estimated $\theta_a$ are not converging, the algorithm still manages to find the best arms. It is acting like a traditional multi-armed bandit problem, but without any use of the contexts as you described. I will try adding a bias as you mention to see if the code is correct. Is my method of calculating regret correct?

Comment: @guy That's an... interesting question which I kinda mistakenly glossed over initially. Edited my thoughts on that into my answer, but it's not quite a conclusive answer.

Comment: Ah, that is a good point. I like your alternate method because of its robustness. On a separate topic, I was thinking that since feeding the LinUCB noise vectors simply results in basic MAB recommendations. Does this mean that if a user comes in with a context vector that is completely uninformative, then the best arms on average will simply be recommended first? (like recommending the bestsellers first given the context is noise)

Comment: @guy Hmmm depends on what an "uninformative" feature vector looks like. If it's uninformative in a consistent manner (e.g. always the same initial / default values for unknown features), then I suppose that's a likely result yes (it should be able to learn what the best action is for such a "consistent-unknown" feature vector). If you initialize unknown feature values completely randomly, that's not consistent, and then I think it'll be more difficult to learn a consistent, solid strategy for such cases.

Comment: That's just what I expect though, I might be wrong. The best thing to do is to try to evaluate what happens in such cases empirically.

Comment: I tried the quick fix of adding a column of 1's to the noise data and I don't see any significance in the results. The learned $\hat{\theta_a}$ seems like noise, the cumulative regret is linear and the MAB seems to simply be acting like before. Am I looking at the wrong thing?

Comment: @guy Hmm if I look at papers such as [this one](http://auai.org/uai2017/proceedings/papers/171.pdf), it looks like cumulative regret plots that at least "look" linear aren't that uncommon in practice. It may simply take more time to learn adequately for a problem with 100 arms. You could try lowering to e.g. 10 arms, see what happens. It looks like proper tuning of the $\alpha$ parameter can also have a significant influence.

Comment: @guy Did you try 10arms as Dennis recommended? I am curious to see if this changed things.

Comment: @Matthew yes i did and it helped clarify what was going on. 10 arms converged much faster so I had faith that the setup was correct, just my convergence was very slow.

Comment: @guy great, thanks for the update! Enjoyed this discourse, Dennis and guy, thanks!